# Importrange when copied to other cells automatically change range

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, importrange

I am using `importrange` to pull data from my responses page to my spreadsheet. I have completed the first sheet but I now need to go into the sheet to follow on where sheet one has run out of space. The problem is I have copied the `importrange` script to all cells in the column, but the range hasn't automatically changed. I want the range to say A2:A2 to change to A3:A3 etc. Can this be done so I don't have to change each one by hand

Here is an example

```
 =IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cBaiqy_VZRvM90XHW4doW6phqZO02OgoFdhNN1COgck/edit", "Time!e18:e18")
```

and I want when copied to the next cell to be

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cBaiqy_VZRvM90XHW4doW6phqZO02OgoFdhNN1COgck/edit", "Time!e19:e19")
```

and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if you want to drag down the formula use:

  ```
  =IMPORTRANGE("1cBaiqy_VZRvM90XHW4doW6phqZO02OgoFdhNN1COgck", "Time!E"&ROW(A18))
  ```
- if you want to drag to the right use:

  ```
  =IMPORTRANGE("1cBaiqy_VZRvM90XHW4doW6phqZO02OgoFdhNN1COgck", "Time!E"&COLUMN(R1))
  ```

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try this out

Comment: That worked great, thanks. Will save a lot of time now 

Comment: One more problem. I am using the following code in many cells of the sheet,      =SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE("" & S2, "(\d)", "$1,"), ",")   not all are going to contain data at any one time. How do I stop the empty cell value notice from appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `A2:A2` use `A2` as it's shorter and also will simplify the IMPORTRANGE formula.

```
=IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cBaiqy_VZRvM90XHW4doW6phqZO02OgoFdhNN1COgck/edit", "Time!e" + row())
```

Instead for `row()` your could use `column()` or any variant like `row() + 5` to get the required row number of the cell to import.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will give that a go later 